# Minimum number of word matches in Lucene / Elasticsearch / Solr

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

The texts I query for (and the queries itself) have on average 11 words (up to about 25). I want my query to return matches only if at least half of the words in query are matched in text.

For example, this is how my initial Lucene query looks like (for simplicity it has only 4 words):

```
jakarta~ apache~ lucene~ stackoverflow~
```

It will return a match if at least one of the words is fuzzy matched but I want it to return a match only if at least any two (half of 4) of the words are fuzzy matched.

Is it possible in Lucene?

I could split my query like this (`OR` is default operator in Lucene):

```
(jakarta~ apache~) AND (lucene~ stackoverflow~)
```

But that wouldn’t return a match is both `jakarta` and `apache` are matched but none of `lucene` and `stackoverflow` is matched.

I could change my query to:

```
(jakarta~ AND apache~) (jakarta~ AND lucene~) (jakarta~ AND stackoverflow~)
(apache~ AND lucene~) (apache~ and stackoverflow~) (lucene~ AND stackoverflow~)
```

Would that be efficient? On average my expression would consist of 462 `AND` clauses (binomial coefficient of 11 and 6), in the worst case of 5200300 `AND` clauses (binomial coefficient of 25 and 13).

If it is not possible (or doesn’t make sense performance wise) to do in Lucene, is it possible in Elasticsearch or Solr?

It should work fast (<= 0.5 sec/search) for at least 10 000 texts in database.

It would be even better if I could easily later change the minimum matches percentage (e.g. 40% instead of 50%) but I may not need this.

Answer (score 2):

All three options support a minimum should match functionality among optional query clauses.

- Lucene:  Set in BooleanQueries via the [`BooleanQuery.Builder.setMinimumShouldMatch`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.Builder.html#setMinimumNumberShouldMatch-int-) method.
- Solr:  The DisMax [`mm` parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm(MinimumShouldMatch)Parameter).
- Elasticsearch: The `minimum_should_match` parameter, in [Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html) queries, [Multi Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) queries, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use `BooleanQuery.Builder.setMinimumShouldMatch` in query parser syntax? I'm using Lucene through Neo4j REST API. I can use custom Lucene analyzer.

Comment: @Rusty - No, the standard query parser doesn't support it I'm afraid, and I'm really not familiar enough with Neo4j to suggest the best approach there.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this thread, so updating that latest I can find on this. As of at least Lucene 9.5 the Standard query parser seems to be supporting the min-should-match in query expression using `@`: eg. (blue crab fish)@2 
  https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html

Answer (score 0):

In Solr, you can use [minimum match (mm) parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm(MinimumShouldMatch)Parameter) with DisMax and eDisMax and you can specify the percentage of the match expected.

Comment: This looks like what I'm after. I'll try Solr then, thanks!